# DI parameters to class library without controller

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.1, class-library

So I'm not sure if I'm just missing something, but basically every example of DI I see with asp.net core shows passing of parameters from the appSettings.json file through a constructor in the controller and then to anything else.

Can I bypass the Controller and just inject directly a Class Library?

For an example of what I'm trying to do, let's say I have appSettings.json with

```
"EmailSettings":{"smtpServer":"mail.example.com", "port":123, "sendErrorsTo":"errors@example.com"}
```

---

Then a Class Library for EmailServices

EmailSettings.cs

```
public class EmailSettings{
   public string smtpServer {get;set;}
   public int port {get;set;}
   public string sendErrorsTo {get;set;}
}
```

IEmailService.cs

```
public interface IEmailService
{
   void SendErrorEmail(string method, Exception ex);
}
```

and EmailService.cs

```
public class EmailService :IEmailService
{
   private readonly EmailSettings _emailSettings;
   public EmailService(EmailSettings emailSettings)
   {
      _emailSettings = emailSettings;
   }
   public void SendErrorEmail(string method, Exception ex)
   {
      ....
   }
}
```

---

Startup.cs in the main asp.net core application

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ...
   services.Configure<EmailSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings"));
   services.AddScoped<IEmailService, EmailService>(p => {
      return new EmailService(p.GetService<EmailSettings>());
   });
   ...
}
```

---

Without loading the EmailServices or the appsetting.json parameters through the controller and then into the BusinessLayer class library, I want to be able to call the SendErrorEmail from BusinessLayer (or any other place).

DoWork.cs

```
public MakeItWork()
{
   try
   {...}
   catch (exception ex)
   {
      IEmailService.SendErrorEmail("BAL - MakeItWork",ex)
   }
}
```

But it just fails with a null exception. The DI in the startup doesn't create the EmailService in place of the IEmailService, and I'm going to guess the parameters are not there either.

Thanks for any help you can give.

**----EDIT----**

I ended up just switching to using AutoFac for DI. It's able to accomplish what I was looking for. Accepted the answer below to give Phantom the points for trying to assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

- In your `MakeItWork()` method, you have code that "calls" a method using the interface name - not even sure how that will compile. You need to use an object of a class that implements that interface to actually make method calls at runtime. For example, in your DoWork class, you could have a constructor requesting for an instance of a class that implements the `IEmailService` interface and store it for future use in other methods.
- Second, in the Services collection, you are adding a "Scoped" dependency (in the `ConfigureServices` method). A "scoped" dependency is only created upon a (http)Request, typically via calls to controllers. From your code and your explanation, it looks like you are wanting to add a Singleton object for your `IEmailService` interface. So, instead of adding a Scoped dependency use `AddSingleton` - as you have done, you can also create the specific object in the call to `AddSingleton` - that means this object will be provided every time you request it (through class constructors, for example). If you are using it as a singleton, you should also make sure that it is thread safe. Alternatively, you can also add the dependency using `AddTransient` - if you use this, a **new** object will be created every time you request it.

Update: 
**Sample Code**

Modify your ConfigureServices to make the EmailService as Transient (this means a new object every time this service is requested):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ...
   services.Configure<EmailSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings"));
   services.AddTransient<IEmailService, EmailService>();
   ...
}
```

Your "DoWork" class should request the EMail Service in the constructor:

```
public class DoWork()
{

private IEmailService _emailService;

//Dependency should be injected here
public DoWork(IEmailService emailService)
{
    _emailService = emailService;
}


public MakeItWork()
{
   try
   {...}
   catch (exception ex)
   {
      //Use the saved email service object to do your work
      _emailService.SendErrorEmail("BAL - MakeItWork", ex)
   }
}

}
```

It doesn't end here. The question remains as to how you are going to create an Object of the DoWork class. For this, one idea is to create an interface for the DoWork class itself and then setup the container for that interface as well. Then wherever you would want to use the DoWork implementation you can "request" the interface for DoWork. Or use the container directly to create an instance.

Comment: Maybe i just completely misunderstood, but i though that from the Startup.cs, the DI there means that anytime a IEmailService is called, then use EmailService, and this line "return new EmailService(p.GetService<EmailSettings>())" is supposed to mean, pass these parameters into the EmailService constructor.  Am I completely misinterpreting what it is supposed to do?

Comment: Dave, I think it may be a good idea to understand the fundamentals before trying to get your code to work (or even understanding what you want). [A good place to start is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Comment: Been there-multiple times, several SO pages, several blogs from other Devs and PluralSight. Posting a question to see if this was even possible was essentially a last resort.

Comment: Added some more notes for you (with sample code - updated original answer).

Comment: Thank you for the update. It does seem that either way, I have to inject something onto the controller to pass it to the BAL. I can't seem to do anything like just calling a static method of EmailService.  I tried earlier to make an interface for DoWork and inject the EmailService directly into that, but was still left with having to place IDoWork into the constructor of the controller to use it. - Again, unless i missing something.  I'm at a point where I have it working, just not how I thought it would go.

Comment: You should place the "DoWork" & corresponding interface in a "Core" library that the asp.net core project can reference. The BAL can also refer to this "Core" library. You can setup the IDoWork interface in the ConfigureServices and then in your BAL, you can inject the DoWork object in the constructor of a BAL class - there is no need to go through the controller.

Comment: Having said the above, it is not clear how you are creating the "BAL" classes. The functionality you are trying to implement (eg: Email Service) is best implemented in some kind of "service" layer - where objects of these classes can be injected where required. Also, you need to consider how to structure your "layer" dependencies as well. You would find some good stuff in [Microsoft's architecture guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/modern-web-apps-azure-architecture/architectural-principles).